# Callback Listener Not Calling Android ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a view model this view model fetch some data from a server which is abstracted in `localBodiesRepository` and I will set the listener from the activity but listener not called at all

```
private const val FETCHED = true
private const val NOT_FETCHED = false

class HomeViewModel(
    private val employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository,
    private val localBodiesRepository: LocalBodiesRepository,
    private val preference: PreferenceProvider
): ViewModel() {
    var mLocalBodiesFetchingListener: LocalBodiesFetchingListener ? = null
    init {
        mLocalBodiesFetchingListener ? .onStarted()
        Coroutines.main {
            try {
                val response = localBodiesRepository.getDistricts()
                if (response.status == "success") {
                    localBodiesRepository.saveDistricts(response.districts)
                    preference.setDistrictFetched(FETCHED)
                    mLocalBodiesFetchingListener ? .onSuccess()
                } else {
                    preference.setDistrictFetched(NOT_FETCHED)
                    mLocalBodiesFetchingListener ? .onFailure(
                        "Loading data failure\nPlease close app and open again"
                    )
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                preference.setDistrictFetched(NOT_FETCHED)
                mLocalBodiesFetchingListener ? .onFailure(
                    e.message !! .plus(
                        "\nLoading data failure\nPlease close app and open again"
                    )
                )
            } catch (e: NoInternetException) {
                preference.setDistrictFetched(NOT_FETCHED)
                mLocalBodiesFetchingListener ? .onFailure(
                    e.message !! .plus(
                        "\nLoading data failure\nPlease close app and open again"
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have set the listener from my home activity

```
class HomeActivity: AppCompatActivity(),
KodeinAware,
LocalBodiesFetchingListener {
    override val kodein by kodein()
    val location: Location by instance()
    val api: AppApi by instance()
    val db: AppDatabase by instance()
    private lateinit
    var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    private val factory: HomeViewModelFactory by instance()
    private lateinit
    var binding: ActivityHomeBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        binding.homeViewModel = homeViewModel
        homeViewModel.mLocalBodiesFetchingListener = this
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
            .apply {
                setMessage("Loading data please wait...")
                setCancelable(false)
                show()
        }
    }
    override fun onStarted() {
        progressDialog ? .show()
    }
    override fun onSuccess() {
        progressDialog ? .dismiss()
    }
    override fun onFailure(message: String) {
        progressDialog ? .dismiss()
        errorToast(message)
    }
```

The `progressDialog` not showing at all 
I don't know why it's not calling but when I was debugging I found the listener is null
maybe this is the issue, then what I need to do

Why the `mLocalBodiesFetchingListener` is null when I am debugging the ViewModel

Comment: Try to pass  mLocalBodiesFetchingListener instance  to  viewmodel in viewmodel constructor  and check, it will work.

Comment: @nikk  is that a good practice

Comment: good practice is to use livedata with viewmodel.. for your problem.. this is the right approach.

Comment: @nikk you mean I have to replace the callbacks with ```LiveData```?

Comment: yep, no need for callbacks, just create livedata ang let your fragment observe those

Comment: Yes you should go for live data.

Comment: here you can see that I have ```ApiException``` and ```NoInternetException``` I have to toast these error also if it goes wrong, how can i if I am creating a ```LiveData<Boolean>```?

Comment: U can use enum or a custom class with as many fields as u need